# ReleaseDC from CWnd overrides ReleaseDC from winuser

Tags: c++, mfc

I have created a simple application to use opengl in conjunction with MFC. The problem is I have the following code

```
ReleaseDC(m_hWnd,m_hDC);
```

This seems correct according to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162920(v=vs.85).aspx

Even intelisense tells me that i am selecting the correct function

The problem is that once I type the function ReleaseDC the compiler automatically looks to the CWnd::ReleaseDC referenced here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ek0dh9wd.aspx . Obviously this gives me a compilation error. I do not know much mfc and any help is welcomed.

I am using visual studio 2015 update 1.

Comment: You can also lookup `CClientDC dc(this);` which is MFC wrapper for `GetDC`, it has automatic cleanup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably call `ReleaseDC(m_hWnd,m_hDC);` from inside a member function of a CWnd derived type, which declares a member function `ReleaseDC`.

To call the global namespace `ReleaseDC`, you must qualify it appropriately:

```
::ReleaseDC(m_hWnd,m_hDC);
```